# Routing problems in ASP.NET Web API if deployed in IIS as child application

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, visual-studio-2013, asp.net-web-api

I have a solution in VS2013 with multiple ASP.NET Web applications. I have added an ASP.NET WebAPI project in the same solution.

After I deployed the WebAPI as a child application in IIS I got the following error:

Multiple types were found that match the controller named 'Account'. This can happen if the route that services this request ('Account/Register') does not specify namespaces to search for a controller that matches the request. If this is the case, register this route by calling an overload of the 'MapRoute' method that takes a 'namespaces' parameter.
The request for 'Account' has found the following matching controllers:
Proj1.Controllers.AccountController
Proj2.Controllers.AccountController

I have tried adding a default namespace to the `RouteConfig.cs` like so:

```
routes.MapRoute(

                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
                namespaces: new string[] { "Proj1.WebAPI.Controllers" }

            );
```

but I still get the same error.

Any ideas?

Comment: you should neet to set parent url before {controller} `url: "parentUrl/{controller}/{action}/{id}"`

Comment: url: "webapi/{controller}/{action}/{id}" returns an HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found

Comment: can you share the whole url which you are trying. and also the snap shots or your iis site directory

Comment: it's a POST to http://localhost/admin/webapi/account/register with a JSON request body

Comment: try this one  `admin/webapi/{controller}/{action}/{id}`

Comment: still the same 404 error..

Comment: please try to add `<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>` under `<system.webServer>`

Comment: sorry that didn't work either, same response

Comment: after adding web config try without parent url like this `{controller}/{action}/{id}`

Comment: I did and got the original error: Multiple types were found that match the controller named Account

Comment: ufff, you need to do this in your WebApiConfig Class `config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "admin/webapi/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );`

Comment: back to 404. @MirzaDanishBaig thanks for your suggestions, I'm really at a loss.

Comment: Did you try this: http://shazwazza.com/post/multiple-webapi-controllers-with-the-same-name-but-different-namespaces/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just needed to add this to my WebApiConfig.cs

```
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "webapi/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );

        **config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "Admin",
            routeTemplate: "{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }**
        );

    }
```

Works perfectly now!